# Django models.FileField(upload_to=function1, default=function2)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to set the default image in a django model with a function. Te reason is that i generate the image (a qrcode) and i want to save it with a model asociated with the request.user, it is working with the upload_to= but fails with the default, it seems it doesn't get the instance.

The code is:
-*- models.py -*-

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django.utils.timezone as timezone
from myproject.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
import os

def function1(instance, filename):
    retun os.path.join(self.uid.username, str(instance.shortname), '.jpg')

def function2(instance):
    return os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, str(instance.username), 'tmp.jpg')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    shortname = models.CharField()
    qr = models.FileField(upload_to=function1, default=function2)
```

this gives the function2() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

i also tried to pass uid as parameter to function2 like this:

```
def function2(uid):
    username = uid.username
    return os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, username, 'tmp.jpg')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    shortname = models.CharField()
    qr = models.FileField(upload_to=function1, default=function2(uid))
```

but this won't work too, gives an AttributeError exception:
'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'username'

Any ideas on how can i tell django to upload a locally generated file (generated on the django machine at MEDIA_ROOT/request.user.username/)

Thanks!!

Comment: Why would you think that the default function would be passed the instance? It is not, and that's consistently the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem from views here:
[Loading Django FileField and ImageFields from the file system](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/dec/03/loading-django-files-from-code/)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! will try them any way!

Comment: This answer conveys the idea that you need to create a django.core.files.File object for FileField first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `instance` instead of `self`. `self` does not exist in `function1` and `function2` scope:

```
def function1(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(instance.uid.username, str(instance.shortname), '.jpg')

def function2(instance):
    return os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, str(instance.username), 'tmp.jpg')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    shortname = models.CharField()
    qr = models.FileField(upload_to=function1, default=function2)
```

You can found docs for `FileField.upload_to` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

You get `function2() takes exactly 1 argument, (0 given)` because `function2` is expecting for `instance` param, and if you try to pass `uid` like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    shortname = models.CharField()
    qr = models.FileField(upload_to=function1, default=function2(uid))
```

will raise an error because at this point `uid` is a `models.ForeignKey` instance. You could try to do this in a [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal:

```
def function2(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    if not instance.qr:
        instance.qr = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, username, 'tmp.jpg')

pre_save.connect(function2, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: the instance vs self was an error while copying the code... i edited it on the first post to correct it Thanks!, tried this but it still says: function2() takes exactly 1 argument, (0 given)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using instance instead of self. Also, `function2` will not be being passed an instance.